# Oracle jdbc driver 11, wrong symbols after migration

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

We are in process of migration from jdk 1.5 and oracle driver 10.2.0.2 to jdk 1.7 and driver 11.1.0.7  Database is oracle 11g. NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8ISO8859P1.

*We faced issue with em-dash, unicode 150 character* (http://www.codetable.net/decimal/150). It is stored in database like 150, I have checked with `select dump(name) from client`

When try to read and write to file this string, it substitutes em-dash with ? (question mark).With old driver and environment with 1.5. Everything was ok, it was in file like em-dash.

I found that locale were changed in new servers, previously it was `en_GB` now it is `C`. So tried to run my java application with following parameters `-Duser.country=GB -Duser.language=en`.

But it doesn't help, what more can I do?

Comment: The data is stored incorrectly.  Decimal 150 is a control character in the ISO 8859-1 character set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). There is no em-dash in ISO 8859-1.  Either change your data so that it is a valid printable character in the database character set or change your database character set to support the set of characters you really want to represent.

Comment: Can you explain why does it work on jdk 1.5 and previous driver version?

Comment: Looks like your data is actually Windows-1252 (aka Cp1252), which basically is ISO-8859-1 + some extra characters, and it has an em-dash for character 150. BTW: Unicode 150 is not em-dash, but also a control character.

Comment: @Sergey - It could have been a bug in the prior version of the driver.  It could be that the driver is now doing a better job of character set conversion.  I know that Oracle's NLS team has been working to make conversion stricter so that people don't have this sort of situation where invalid data might look ok from some applications but not others or where incorrect configuration settings allowed applications to get invalid data into the database in the first place.  That may be the issue here.